# Auto-convert Microsoft Publisher 2010 documents to HTML or PDF

Tags: pdf, document-converter

Can anyone think of a way to automatically convert Microsoft Publisher 2010 (.PUB) documents to either HTML or PDF upon upload to a document library for viewing within a publishing site?

We are implementing a SharePoint portal and have hundreds of .PUB files that we need to be able to have users view that do not have Microsoft Publisher installed.  I realize that Publisher can "Save As PDF" but these documents get updated frequently (plus there are hundreds of them) and then we would need to maintain both the PDF and PUB versions within the site. We'd prefer to have a method whereby we could upload the .PUB to the site and then have it converted to a more universal format so it could be viewed within a browser or PDF reader.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Muhimbi PDF Converter for SharePoint. It allows conversion of most common file types including Publisher. Comes with a friendly User Interface, Nintex and SharePoint Designer workflow activities as well as a complete API.

Disclaimer, I worked on this product so consider me biased.